# i am downloading a div as image in pdf using jquery .it is downloading but the text in tha image looks blur.anyone please explain why?

Tags: jquery

i am downloading a div as image  in pdf using  jquery .it is downloading but the text in the image looks blur.anyone please explain why?

---

```js
   var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
        doc.addHTML($(".genealogy"), 50, 50, {
          'background': '#fff',
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        }, function () {

            doc.save('genealogy.pdf');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the canvas method that jsPDF uses check: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/339

There are some workarounds mentioned but it might not be working for you. The main problem is that the html is being threated like an image, and in the process the image might get scaled and deliver bad quality in the end.

Comment: Than I am afraid you need to wait for a newer version or use a different tool.